# Rails - Create object from same table for Google charts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

Basically I have a model called ServerStatus, and I need to create an object to pass into google charts.

```
ServerStatus Schema:
#  config_id    :integer
#  count        :integer
#  success      :boolean
#  failure      :boolean
#  generated_at :datetime
```

The object needs to be in the format:

```
data_table.add_row([ datetime, success, failure])
```

The datetime field is called `generated_at`, and the `success` and `failure` are both booleans, each with an associated count (seperate field).

I am currently doing the following:

```
ServerStatus.find(:all, :conditions => {:config_id => options[:config_id], :success => true, :generated_at => options[:start_date].beginning_of_day..options[:end_date].end_of_day}, :order => 'generated_at ASC').each do |s|
ServerStatus.find(:all, :conditions => {:config_id => options[:config_id], :failure => true, :generated_at => options[:start_date].beginning_of_day..options[:end_date].end_of_day}, :order => 'generated_at ASC').each do |f|
        data_table.add_row([ s.generated_at.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)'), s.count, f.count])
      end
    end
```

Doing it this way adds the generated_at time twice, so the graph for the `:failure => true` plots incorrectly. How can I select all where `success = true` and `failure = true` and map the counts for each to the `generated_at` time, taking into account null vales for either when mapping to time.

Answer (score 0):

You can run two separate queries:
 1) find all where success = true 
 2) find all where failure = true

Then add the two arrays returned by the above steps.

Finally, iterate through this newly formed array and populate your data_table.

I failed to understand the need of two variables: success & failure.  Can you have success & failure both true/false at the same time for the same record?  What I got from the brief definition of your ServerStatus, I don't think it's really necessary.  You can very well do with just one variable.

**Example**

```
server_status = ServerStatus.find(<your condition>)
server_status.each do |status|
 data_table.add_row([status.generated_at, server_status.success, !server_status.success])
end
```